# collection_select and not being submitted database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a small problem and it is really bugging me.

I have all the standard scaffold code in the controllers to give me the standard CRUD features.

The collection_select form helper is in my view:

```
    <%= collection_select(:link,:category_id,@categories,:id,"name") %>
```

The Link Table has a category_id column. This is being posted ok, as while debugging it gives:`
...
 "link"=>{"name"=>"",
 "category_id"=>"1",
 ...

However it is not being submitted to the database and any validation of the category_id fails.

Controller Methods:

```
 def new
    @link = Link.new
    @categories = Category.find(:all)
  end

  def create
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])
    if @link.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created link."
      redirect_to @link
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Form from View

```
<% form_for @link do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>......
```

Comment: Can you also post the bit from your controller code that is grabbing the params and sending to model? Also the beginning of your form that has this collection_select helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it, I checked the logs and it had this error:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: category_id
```

I added the 'category_id' to the attr_accesible' in my model and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Change your collection_select from

```
 <%= collection_select(:link,:category_id,@categories,:id,"name") %>
```

to

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:category_id,@categories,:id,"name") %>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, nothing gets entered into the database and the validates_presence_of still fails.